# Problems importing a Zbrush collada model into Xcode 6.2

Tags: xml, 3d, xcode6, collada

Google returned no results.

The model was created and exported from Zbrush and is proprietary and I cannot post it.

The first time I loaded the file, there were no errors.  I exited Xcode flushed the derived data directory and now I get this error.

> file:///.file/id=6571367.132290036: warning: File Consistency Issue:
>   Line 0: Found 2 elements with the same ID "dogtest_"

I then ran

`xmllint --noout --schema http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4_1.xsd dogtest.dae`

and it returns

> dogtest.dae:154: element node: Schemas validity error : Element
>   '{http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema}node', attribute 'id':
>   'dogtest_' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:ID'.
>   dogtest.dae fails to validate

lines from 154 are about a node

```
<node id="dogtest_" name="dogtest_" type="NODE">
        <translate sid="translate">0 0 0</translate>
        <rotate sid="rotateZ">0 0 1 0</rotate>
        <rotate sid="rotateY">0 1 0 0</rotate>
        <rotate sid="rotateX">1 0 0 0</rotate>
        <scale sid="scale">1 1 1</scale>
        <instance_geometry url="#dogtest_">
          <bind_material>
            <technique_common>
              <instance_material symbol="dogtest__blinnSG" target="#dogtest__blinn">
                <bind_vertex_input semantic="TEX0" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" input_set="0"/>
              </instance_material>
            </technique_common>
          </bind_material>
        </instance_geometry>        
      </node>
```

Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: have you tried import some stub model? Like cube or something?

Comment: The artist is sending me some now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, read the xml schema.  I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Zbrush.

was

```
<node id="dogtest_" name="dogtest_" type="NODE">
```

is

```
<node id="MYdogtest_" name="dogtest_" type="NODE">
```

now validates

```
xmllint --noout --schema http://www.khronos.org/files/collada_schema_1_4_1.xsd dogtest.dae
dogtest.dae validates
```